# Post incrementing a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I  was going through exercise problem from Stoyan stefanov book named Object oriented Javascript.

Problem :

```
var s = 'ls';
s++;
```

When I execute this in chrome, I get NaN.

For the same code above if I do

```
var s = 'ls';
    s = s+1;
```

I get output as ls1

Can anyone please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: What is your expectation when you do `s++;` on a string ?

Comment: Basically, `+= 1` is not equivalent to `++`.

Comment: @alfasin because s++ and s=s+1 are same. so I thought result  would be ls1

Comment: @roxid well surprise, they're not the same :)

Comment: @alfasin am I missing some concept here?

Comment: `++` is called the ["increment" operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/increment-and-decrement-operators-javascript). Can you increment a string?

Comment: Yes I know. But I thought that since s++ is equivalent to s=s+1 and since its javascript so anything can happen . :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`++` tries to convert `x` as number first. Hence failed because `x` is having `string` value and return `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do ++ its attempting to increment a number. When you use the + sign, it's either adding or concatenating. Its "smart" and see's that s is a string, so it concatenates it with 1. With ++, you can't increment a string so you get NaN (Not a number)

Answer (score 0):

s++ is an increment operation which is commonly performed for numbers hence the output nan( not a number). In the second case you are doing a concatenation operation. So the ‘ls’ + 1 gives ‘ls1’.

Answer (score 0):

You can't increment strings via `++`. That operator is reserved exclusively for the `number` primitive. Instead Try:

```js
var s = 'ls';

s += 1;

console.log(s);
```

The above is syntactic sugar for what you originally posted ([string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)):

```
s = s + 1;
```